# Is the difference between >50% and <50%, significant?

Tags: probability

In one of the video-games that I play, there are these options called skills. Skills are customization options. They're mutually exclusive. Acquiring them requires expenditure of a finite resource, so I can't get all of these skills and I want to choose the best to use. Now, some skills are probability based, like "have a(n) X% chance for this awesome thing to happen every time you do Y".

Here's my question: My rubric is to practically ignore those skills which I cannot get past a 50 % chance of triggering. Is this binary judgment of the two sides of the half-way point a good way to roll? The difference can be infinitesimal, yet I can define it as the difference between probable and improbable.
To put it another way, is it folly to invest in probabilities below 50%?

Comment: As I think on it, I can imagine steps to answering the question, but I'm looking for a comprehensive answer. I also wonder if I should be asking this in Arqade (gaming Stack Exchange) instead. Part of the answer would include, what skills am I comparing these chance skills to? How often do I think that I will use non-chance skills vs. chance? Example: A 1% chance to, say, earn a skill point every few seconds is more valuable than a 51% chance to earn a temporary skill point every minute, given enough time and patience.

Comment: If some skill has 40% success rate, then when you do it twice in a row there is a > 60% chance that you succeed at least once. So if some skills are awesome enough to spend several turns doing, maybe you want to use them too.